# How can i display the interfaces inside a particular object path in DBus

Tags: linux, dbus, gdbus

I need to use a terminal command.
I can use gdbus also.
I have the bus name the object path 
i need to display all the interface inside the object path

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `gdbus` command line tool you should be able to do something like this:

```
gdbus introspect --session --object-path <your object path here> --dest <your bus name here> --xml --recurse
```

For example, to introspect PulseAudio on my machine I can do:

```
gdbus introspect --session --object-path /org/pulseaudio/server_lookup1 --dest org.PulseAudio1 --xml --recurse
```

In the XML produced you should be able to see, among other things, the names of interfaces.

On my Debian machine `gdbus` comes from the package `libglib2.0-bin`.